# How to get the repeated letter in a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var a = "aaaaaaaaaabbffddcccuuekkjjmlotcfshhh";
```

Here I want to get the maximum and minimum entered values.For example, I have entered letter "a" as 10 times. That was the maximum. So I want to pint that value. How can I get the maximum entered values in a String using jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A proposal with [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and an object `count`:

```js
var a = "aaaaaaaaaabbffddcccuuekkjjmlotcfshhh",
    count = {}, min, max;

a.split('').forEach(function (a) {
    count[a] = (count[a] || 0) + 1;
});
Object.keys(count).forEach(function (a, i) {
    if (!i) {
        min = [a];
        max = [a];
        return;
    }
    if (count[a] < count[min[0]]) {
        min = [a];
        return;
    }
    if (count[a] > count[max[0]]) {
        max = [a];
        return;
    }
    if (count[min[0]] === count[a]) {
        min.push(a);
    }
    if (count[max[0]] === count[a]) {
        max.push(a);
    }
});

document.write('min: ' + min.join(', ') + ' with occurrence of ' + count[min[0]] + '<br>');
document.write('max: ' + max.join(', ') + ' with occurrence of ' + count[max[0]] + '<br>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(count, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Nina Scholz

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the maximum entered values in a String using jquery or
>   javascript.

try this

```
var a = "aaaaaaaaaabbffddcccuuekkjjmlotcfshhh";
var allchars = a.split("").sort();
var output = {}; 
allchars.forEach(function(val){ output[val] = output[val] || 0; output[val]++; });
```

Now find the key with highest value

```
var highestProp = "";
var highestValue = 0;
var lowestProp = "";
var lowestValue = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;        
Object.keys(output).forEach(function(key){
   if (output[key] > highestValue )
   {
      highestValue = output[key];
      highestProp = key;
   }
   if (output[key] < lowestValue )
   {
      lowestValue  = output[key];
      lowestProp  = key;
   }
});
```

Now  `highestValue` and `highestProp` has the highest values and highest-value property name. Similarly `lowestValue` and `lowestProp` has the lowest values and lowest-value property name.

**DEMO**

```js
var a = "aaaaaaaaaabbffddcccuuekkjjmlotcfshhh";
var allchars = a.split("").sort();
var output = {}; 
allchars.forEach(function(val){ output[val] = output[val] || 0; output[val]++; });

var highestProp = "";
var highestValue = 0;
var lowestProp = "";
var lowestValue = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
Object.keys(output).forEach(function(key){
   if (output[key] > highestValue )
   {
      highestValue = output[key];
      highestProp = key;
   }
   if (output[key] < lowestValue )
   {
      lowestValue  = output[key];
      lowestProp  = key;
   }
}); 

alert(highestProp + " has the highest frequency of " + highestValue);
alert(lowestProp + " has the lowest frequency of " + lowestValue);
```

Comment: This is what I expect. Thanku you so much.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla I have no clue :)

Comment: @gurvinder372..don't know why people downvote without a reason..;(

Comment: @sathishkumar do you also want min value?

Comment: if we put less than "<" we can get min value right?